# javascript [object Window] in a concat string

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I am trying to loop through and adding based on the respected data-type.
I assume that ID and Type will be put together in the code below, but I am getting [object Window] in place of ID instead.
Here is my Code:

```
//List array FriendID and Type
var friendArray=[];

$('.active').each(function(i, obj) {
    friendID = $(this).siblings('span:first').data('type');
    console.log(friendID); //#1
    friendType = $(this).data('type');      
    friendStr = toString(friendID).concat(friendType);
    console.log(friendStr); //#2
    //Loop through & Add
    if(friendArray.indexOf(friendStr) == -1) {
        friendArray.push(friendStr);
    }
});
```

The friendID marked #1 shows the correct #, i.e `5, 4, 6` and etc...
However, friendStr marked #2 shows `["[object Window]Type1", "[object Window]Type2", "[object Window]Type1"]` when printed...

If I removed the toString() function, the console will give me a friendID.concat error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because calling `toString(friendID)` is invoking the `window.toString()` method which returns `[object Window]`, you can just say

```
String(friendID).concat(friendType);
//or
'' + friendID + friendType
//or just
friendID + friendType //since friendType is a string
```

Comment: How do I go about changing the code so it prints correctly with the #s?

Comment: Or `'' + friendID` or it is not at all required as `friendID` is number and `friendType` is string

Comment: I'll select you as answer when the time limit restriction expires... Thank you so much!

Comment: `toString()` is only called with `window` as the `this` value in non-strict mode. In strict mode, the `this` value will be `undefined`, and thus `toString()` will probably produce something different than `"[object Window]"`. Also note the global object does not have an own `toString`, and its [[Prototype]] is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Oriol I don't think it has anything to do with `this`, as `this` in the `each` loop is referring to the dom element...

Comment: @RobG `friendID` is not a string... but since `friendType` is that will do

Comment: @RobG not really... I think OP is using jQuery... so if `data-type` in the `span` is a number then the `data('type')` will do the type conversion and return the value... http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/odaedLn8/6/ - see the logging for `friendId`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92158/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-robg).

Comment: @Orio—in Chrome and IE, the global object doesn't inherit from *Object.prototype* and the behaviour of their *toString* method is not defined other than as "implementation dependant".